# setting Date value on LocalStorage

Tags: reactjs

I would like some help to set this date Value into a LocalStorage and then When reloading the app, I would like that the default value of the date component was retrieved from local Storage. Right Now, I'm Using TextField with type date on React js.

```
const [dateBegin,setDateBegin] = React.useState(new Date())



 <TextField
                        id="date"
                           label="Início "
                        type="date"
                        multiline={false}

                        onChange={

                            (e)=>{setDateBegin(new Date( e.target.value));
                            localStorage.setItem('@legis/datebegin',dateBegin) 
                                
                        }}
                        InputLabelProps={{
                            color:'secondary',
                            className:"DatePicker",
                        style : {color:"#ffff",},
                        shrink: true,
                        
                        }}
                        inputProps={{
                            style: { color: "#ffff" },
                          }}
                          
                        />
                        <div style = {{marginLeft:50}}>  

                       <TextField
```

However, This is not working right now. Would please help me how to set the date value and then when to retrieve, and if possible how to set the default value of this TextField as the value I retrieved from localStorage?

Answer (score 0):

You trying to save a `Date` object in local storage where it accepts `string` only as the key value.

You can parse the string date you saving and then it'll work fine or as an alternative, use a string date format if possible in your use case:

```js
const dateObjFromString = new Date(localStorage.getItem('date'))
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what @Dvir Hazout said, if you read from a state variable right after setting it, the value will always be stale.

```
const [val, setVal] = useState(1)

return (
    <div
        onClick={() => {
            setVal(2)
            console.log(val) // logs 1 on first click, 2 on subsequent clicks
        }}
    />
)
```

Instead, you need to assign it to a normal variable:

```
const [val, setVal] = useState(1)

return (
    <div
        onClick={() => {
            const newVal = 2

            setVal(newVal)
            console.log(newVal) // works as expected
        }}
    />
)
```